# In PHP find duplicate entry in a multi dimensional array then sum the values in a specific key of that array

Tags: php

I have an array that was created from a CSV file.  The array contains the following.  Basically it has four lines and six columns.  I.E. it is multi dimensional.

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [WBS Element] => 1234567.01 
        [Proj System Status] => 
        [CY Actuals] => 579373 
        [ITD Actuals] => 696,609 
        [Overall Commitment] => 
        [Overall Assigned] => 696,609 
        [CYSpent] => 579,373 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [WBS Element] => 1234567.02 
        [Proj System Status] => 
        [CY Actuals] => 86689 
        [ITD Actuals] => 86,689 
        [Overall Commitment] => 
        [Overall Assigned] => 86,689 
        [CYSpent] => 86,689 ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [WBS Element] => 1234567.02.01 
        [Proj System Status] => 
        [CY Actuals] => 10750 
        [ITD Actuals] => 86,689 
        [Overall Commitment] => 
        [Overall Assigned] => 86,689 
        [CYSpent] => 86,689 ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [WBS Element] => 1234567.02.02 
        [Proj System Status] => 
        [CY Actuals] => 22756 
        [ITD Actuals] => 86,689 
        [Overall Commitment] => 
        [Overall Assigned] => 86,689 
        [CYSpent] => 86,689 ) 
    )
```

You will notice that one of my keys "WBS Element" has a value in it where the first ten characters might match another row in the array.  What I need to accomplish is to take any row where the first ten characters of the "WBS Element" match and sum the other columns together so that the result is a aggregated array with the same columns but no rows with the first ten characters matching.

Hopefully that makes sense what I am trying to accomplish.  I am new when it comes to PHP so any help would be appreciated.  I ahve gotton a column summerization to work but I can't figure out to search an array for "matching" keys then combine those together by summing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user729691: It always help if you actually post an example of the expected result.

Comment: Good point, I will do that next time :-)  thanks again for the help!

Comment: @danielmesh since you continue to use StackOveflow, you can improve this question at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $row)
{
  $key = substr($row['WBS Element'],0,10);

  $new_array[$key]['WBS Element'] = $key; // optional
  $new_array[$key]['Proj System Status'] += $row['Proj System Status'];
  $new_array[$key]['CY Actuals'] += $row['CY Actuals'];
  $new_array[$key]['ITD Actuals'] += $row['ITD Actuals'];
  // same for Overall Commitment, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would loop through each array and

1. create an array of possible 10-character matches
2. if a match is found, add the rest of the columns to that match

This assumes that there can be multiple 10-character strings that can match:

```
$stats = <your array from above>
$output = array();

foreach($stats as $stat){
    // first we create an element in the array so we can sum
    $key = substr($stat['WBS Element'], 0, 10);
    if (!array_key_exists($stat['WBS Element'], $output)){
        $output[$key] = array();
    }

    // sum up rest of columns based on $output[$key]
    // or simply create them if the if-statement was matched above
    $output[$key]['CYSpent'] += $stat['CYSpent'];
    // etc
}
```

this will give you an output of

```
array(
    [10-char-key-1] => array(
        // columns
    )
    [10-char-key-2] => array(
        // columns
    )
    // etc
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quik reply, it works great!  I just can't figure out how to now sum the column.  The column I am working with is "CY Actuals".  Let me know if you need more information :-)  Thanks again for the help, this is brilliant!  I am loving PHP

Comment: With the code above with the $output Key of "CY Actuals" I get the following result.  

Array ( [1234567.01] => Array ( [CY Actuals] => 579373 ) [1234567.02] => Array ( [CY Actuals] => 22756 ) ) 

I need to get this result:

Array ( [1234567.01] => Array ( [CY Actuals] => 579373 ) [1234567.02] => Array ( [CY Actuals] => 120195 ) )