# Finding duplicates, adding their integer values and deleting the duplicates PHP

Tags: php, integer, duplicates

Ok. I'm currently trying to work on the aggregation technique for a college project (Metasearch engine).  I've got three search engines with three arrays.  Each array is like this:

```
// Array created to store the query results
$GoogleArray = array ();

//Top score for Rank 1
$score=100;
//Prefix/specifier to be replaced by space for comparing the URL
$prefix = array ('http://','https://','www.');

//The variables will now be populated with values from the json(results)
foreach($js->items as $item){
    $link2 =  str_replace ($prefix, '', $item->link );
    $link = $item->link;
    $title = $item->title;
    $snippet = $item->snippet;
    //Decrements through score for each result
    $scores = $score--;
    $GoogleArray[] = array($link, $title, $snippet, $scores, $link2);
}
```

I've merged the three arrays into one large list (which is great):

```
//Find duplicates:Step3:Merge Arrays (one long list)
$MergedArr=array_merge($BingArray, $GoogleArray, $BlekkoArray);
```

Then I need to find the duplicates, add their scores together (so the top score goes to the top of the aggregated list; sort array later on) and remove the duplicate entry:

```
//Find duplicates:Step4:Find the duplicates and add them together (re-score)
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821948/
/////////////////////////////////////////////

$newArr = array();

//sum the values in a specific key of that array
foreach($MergedArr as $row){
    if($link2===$link2){
        $key = substr($row[4],0);

        $newArr[$key][0]=$row[0];
        $newArr[$key][1]=$row[1];
        $newArr[$key][2]=$row[2];
        $newArr[$key][3]+=$row[3]; //adding the values (int) here ("Scores")
    }else{
        echo "There are no duplicates";
    }
}
```

Step 4 does those things but now it is like $newArr["trimmed URL here"][3]; and I need to sort them in a descending order [array_multisort()] but not entirely sure if it will work properly due to the $key change.

Is their a better way to do Step 4 or can I still precede with a multisort?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
array(30) { 

[0]=> array(5) 

{ 
[0]=> string(35) "http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/" 
[1]=> string(20) "Speakeasy Speed Test" 
[2]=> string(109) "Test your Internet Connection with Speakeasy's reliable and accurate broadband speed test. What's your speed?" 
[3]=> int(100) 
[4]=> string(24) "speakeasy.net/speedtest/" 
} 

[1]=> array(5) 

{ 
[0]=> string(20) "http://www.test.com/" 
[1]=> string(12) "Test Central" 
[2]=> string(158) "Test.com provides a complete software solution for creating online tests and managing enterprise and specialist certification programs, in up to 22 languages." 
[3]=> int(99) 
[4]=> string(9) "test.com/" 
} 

[2]=> array(5)

{ 
[0]=> string(33) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" 
[1]=> string(39) "Test - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" 
[2]=> string(165) "Test, TEST or Tester may refer to: Contents 1 Assessment 2 Science and technology 3 People 4 Media 5 Other 6 See also Assessment Test (assessment), an assessment ..." 
[3]=> int(98) 
[4]=> string(26) "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" 
}
```

Just an example of some of the array after a var_dump($MergedArr);